# Apache2 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache2

I just installed apache2 no my clean ubuntu 12.10 install (64-bit)

I installed it, copied the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default to /etc/apache2/sites-available/afflicto

Here's the contents of "afflicto" site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /home/afflicto/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /home/afflicto/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course, I opened nautilus, navigated to my home directory for the user "afflicto", which is me and created the www folder as well as some html files.

Then of course I:

```
sudo a2dissite default && sudo a2ensite afflicto
```

But no..

```
403 Forbidden
```

I'm sure this is a simply issue but I'm not very good at this :P

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to debug the issue

- Please increase the `LogLevel` to at least `info` or better `debug`.
- Please investigate the error log.
- Please provide detailed information about the *url* you want to access.

#### Most likely problem

The apache httpd server process run as user `www-data` in group `www-data`.
Can this user access the document behind your url ?

#### Note

1. You may also want to have a look for [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html)

   > This module allows user-specific directories to be accessed using the [http://example.com/~user/](http://example.com/%7Euser/) syntax.
2. A normal site `DocumentRoot` shouldn't be below the home directory of a normal user. This may lead to security degradation introduced by a slightly misconfiguration.